# Apex: Get public link of a file uploaded to Google drive service account

Tags: google-drive-api, file-permissions, apex

I was able to upload an image file to google drive (Service Account) using google drive API. In return of the post, I got a filId from google.

[Uploaded file to drive](https://i.stack.imgur.com/64BRB.png)

I then used this fileId to create public read-only permission on the file.

[added permission to file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tiH4K.png)

But how do I get the public URL for the file? (I am using V3 of drive API)

I tried using "webContentLink":"https://drive.google.com/uc?id={FileID}&export=download" but the downloaded file is corrupted and not opening.

I also tried using "alternateLink": "https://drive.google.com/file/d/{FileId}/view?usp=drivesdk" but this also not working.

[trying to view alternateLink](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BXWwd.png)

Here is my method to upload file to drive:

```
public static String uploadFile(String accesstoken,String FolderId, blob file, String filetype, String filename){
    String thumbnailLink;
    String fid;
    String clink;
    try{
        if(String.isBlank(accesstoken) || file.size()==0 || String.isBlank(filetype) || String.isBlank(filename)){
            throw new applicationException('One or more required parameters are not passed!');
        }
    }catch(applicationException e){
        System.debug(LoggingLevel.ERROR,'Call exception ' + e.getMessage());
    }
    String boundary = '----------9889464542212';
    String delimiter = '\r\n--' + boundary + '\r\n';
    String close_delim = '\r\n--' + boundary + '--';
    String bodyEncoded = EncodingUtil.base64Encode(file);
    String body = '';
    if(FolderId !=''){
        body = delimiter + 'Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8\r\n\r\n' + '{ "name" : "' + filename + '",' + ' "mimeType" : "' + filetype + '",' + '"parents":[{"id":"'+ FolderId +'"}]}' + delimiter + 'Content-Type: ' + filetype + '\r\n' + '\r\n' + bodyEncoded + close_delim;
    }
    else{            
        body = delimiter + 'Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8\r\n\r\n' + '{ "name" : "' + filename + '",' + ' "mimeType" : "' + filetype + '"}'+ delimiter + 'Content-Type: ' + filetype + '\r\n' + '\r\n' + bodyEncoded + close_delim;
    }

    System.debug('Body: '+body);

    try{
        Http http = new Http();
        HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
        req.setEndpoint('https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v3/files?uploadType=multipart&withLink=true');
        req.setHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + accesstoken);
        req.setHeader('Content-Type', 'multipart/related; boundary="' + boundary + '"');
        req.setHeader('Content-length', String.valueOf(body.length()));
        req.setBody(body);
        req.setMethod('POST');
        req.setTimeout(60 * 1000);
        HttpResponse resp = http.send(req);
        System.debug(resp.getBody());

        system.debug('Test');
        Map<String, Object> p = (Map<String, Object>) JSON.deserializeUntyped(resp.getBody());
        thumbnailLink= (String) p.get('thumbnailLink');
        fid=(String) p.get('id');
        System.debug('File Id: '+fid);
        clink='https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id='+fid;
        System.debug('clink: '+clink);
    } catch
        (Exception e) {
            System.debug(LoggingLevel.ERROR,
                         'Call exception ' + e.getMessage());
        }
    String body1 = '{"role":"reader","type":"anyone"}';
    try{
        //Changing file permission to public viewable using link
        Http http = new Http();
        HttpRequest req1 = new HttpRequest();
        req1.setEndpoint('https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/'+fid+'/permissions');
        req1.setHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + accesstoken);
        req1.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        req1.setHeader('Content-length', String.valueOf(body1.length()));
        req1.setBody(body1);
        req1.setMethod('POST');
        req1.setTimeout(60 * 1000);
        HttpResponse resp1 = http.send(req1);
        System.debug(resp1.getBody());
    } catch
        (Exception e) {
            System.debug(LoggingLevel.ERROR,
                         'Call exception ' + e.getMessage());
        }
    return fid;

}
```

Comment: Hello! Can you see the file correctly in your Drive? What is the `mimeType`?

Comment: Hey! Its a Service account and hence I can't visually inspect the file in the drive but I was able to query the binary content of the file back and verify it.
Also "mimeType": "image/jpeg".

Comment: I see, can you try to do the same with a regular user Drive account? If it fails, try to upload the file manually using the UI and see if the download is corrupted too.

Comment: #UPDATE 1:
All drives have a default pdf named "Getting started".
I was able to add "public, read-only" permission to that file and view the file using the 'alternate link' of the file.
This suggest there is something wrong with the upload method. Could someone help me out?

Comment: #UPDATE 2: After some trial and error I was able to share the file uploaded to my Service Account with my normal Google account. Now I can see the file under the "Shared With Me" section of my normal drive.

Comment: Link to file:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1PyczJatbZ7IvB4faHts-J4FN_wqAMweb/view?usp=sharing